# Prove the only normal unipotent subgroup $G$ is trivial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic subgroup of $GL_n(k)$ which acts irreducibly on $V = k^n$, via the natural morphism $G \hookrightarrow GL_n(k)$, where $k= \overline{k}$.

How to prove that  the only normal unipotent subgroup $G$ is trivial one?

Let $N$ be the normal unipotent subgroup of $G$, we can also assume that $N$ is subgroup of $U_n(k)$, but the irreducibility condition confused me, I didn't konw how to use it to solve this question.

Any help will be appreicate.

Comment: When you write "the" do you mean "an"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yeah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N$ is a unipotent group, there exists $n\in N$ such that for every $x\in V$, $n(x)=x$ (see the reference). Let $g\in G$ and $n\in N$, $n(g(x))=g(n'(x))$, $n'\in N$, we deduce that $n(g(x))=g(x)$ and $n$ is the identity since $G$ acts irreducibly on $V$.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54161/reference-request-representations-of-unipotent-groups-have-a-fixed-point

Comment: What the mean" there exists $x \in V$ such that for every $x\in V, n(x) = x$", is "for every  $n\in N, n(x) = x$"?